# Set network for remote connection

Tags: networking, router, network-shares, home-networking, routing

I would like to setup my network for remote connection in a different way than normal.
I have two computers connected and sharing files through LAN with one router.
then each computer has a modem with its own IP address to two different ISP.
one computer has static IP address and the other computer dynamic IP.
my question is: is it possible for me to remote control (the dynamic ip computer) by getting through the static IP since both computers are connected through LAN?
I already know I could install NoIP software to update the IP or a few other options that do work but this method is only for learning purposes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe (as I have not tested this and I can't say for sure if it would work or not)

Assumption:

- PC1 has 2 IP address (192.168.1.100 for LAN, and 10.1.1.100 for Modem/Public IP)
- PC2 has 2 IP address (192.168.1.200 for LAN, and 10.1.2.200 for Modem/Public IP - Dynamic)
- PCOutSideLAN is trying to connect to PC2, but entering PC1 Public IP Address 10.1.1.100

I don't know what OS you used on both PC, so this will be a fairly generic idea of what may be done.

You can set up a Port Forwarding on PC1 so if there is an incoming connection on a specific port, it will get forwarded from PC1 to PC2 192.168.1.200.

Assuming you are connecting using SSH (port 22), then you can set up port Forwarding rule on PC1 that forwards any incoming connection to Port 22 -> 192.168.1.200:22 (and change port as necessary).

Based on this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525703/port-forwarding-in-windows

You just need to run the command below on PC1:

> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3389 listenaddress=10.1.1.100 connectport=3389 connectaddress=192.168.1.200

The above command will create a port proxy, on IPv4, that listens on your Public IP address (10.1.1.100) on remote desktop port (port 3389), and forward that request (received on that IP) to the remote PC with the connectport and connectaddress details.

You just need to change the IP address to match your system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using windows 8 and Windows XP but I can install other if necessary

Comment: @XK8ER Edited the answer with details on how to do Port Forwarding on Windows